# Runtime error - Java

Tags: java, runtime-error, fibonacci

I was trying to find sum of even fibonacci number for a given set of N inputs(obtained from stdin)

This code is working well for some test cases but printing runtime error(No details given) for a test case.

Link for question: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler002

#### code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
    public static  Integer[] convert(int[] chars) {
        Integer[] copy = new Integer[chars.length];
        Arrays.fill(copy, 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
            copy[i] = Integer.valueOf(chars[i]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
                int x, max;
        int a[], sum[], fib[]; 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
       x = in.nextInt();
        a = new int[x];
        sum = new int[x];
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            {
                a[i] = in.nextInt();
            }
        Integer[] b = convert(a);
        max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(b));
        fib = new int[max];
        if (max >1)
            {
        fib[0]=1;
        fib[1]=1;            
        }
        for(int i=2;i<max;i++)
            {
            fib[i] = fib[i-1]+fib[i-2];
        }
        for(int i =0;i<x;i++)
            {
            for(int j = 0;fib[j]<a[i];j++)
                {
                if(fib[j]%2 ==0)
                    sum[i] = sum[i] + fib[j];
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            {
            System.out.println(sum[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

I'll be more thankful if you can help me with an optimized version of the same.

Comment: Could you indicate where in your code you are having problems?

Comment: Indicating the exact runtime error would be beneficial too.

Comment: fibonacci is world worse problem so some cases even super computers take 100 years to get the answers

Comment: luckily his max is defined as an integer, so no need to worry about computational time.

Comment: Explain the purpose of this: `for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) { a[i] = in.nextInt(); }`  Why are you filling the array with values entered by the user?  And, worse, why are you NOT prompting the user?  Is the user supposed to guess when and the type of inputs required?

Comment: @IsuruMadusanka:  If you implement it in a certain way, you can get linear time performance out of it.  Arguably, the larger the number, the longer it'd take for an answer, of course, but still...

Comment: @DavidB It was a coding contest in hackerrank.com. And they do not specify where I had the problem and they even do not tell the error type.

Comment: Here is the link of question : https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler002

Comment: @user3391849 Why would you not test it yourself before submitting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsEception in some cases.

Let's consider what you are doing :

- You are getting an input `x` from user
- Then you create array `a` with `x` elements, input by user
- Then you find the `max` element of `a`
- You create an array `fib` of `max` elements, and calculate `fib[i]` for each `i` from `0` to `max-1`

Suppose the user inputs : 2 2 2

max would be 2, so fib would contain two elements : {1,1}

Now, the following loop will cause the exception :

```
    for(int i =0;i<x;i++) // x is 3
    {
        for(int j = 0;fib[j]<a[i];j++) // both fib[0] and fib[1] < a[0]
                                       // fib[2] would throw the exception
```

It is not clear what you are trying to do with this nested loop, but clearly it doesn't work.

Comment: x is the number of inputs being given. So in the loop the value of 'x' would be 2 but not 3. However I had posted the link of my question. Please do consider looking into it. If my question was not clear.

Comment: @user3391849 I meant that in the example 2 2 2 is the actual array (assuming x is 3)

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that the Recursive call stack in java is so deep,so the java compiler will print RE. and to optimize this problem, frist,you can use the dp method to solve this problem。the dp method is to decrease the repeat count to the problem.
the link is http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A8%E6%80%81%E8%A7%84%E5%88%92 
hope to help you.

Comment: You think or are you sure? Answers are not supposed to be guesses.